# C++ Read file line by line then split each line using the delimiter

Tags: c++

i have searched and got a good grasp of the solution from a previous post but I am still stuck a bit.

My problem is instead of "randomstring TAB number TAB number NL"

My data is "number (space colon space) number (space colon space) sentence"

I've edited the code below but still can't get it to work 100% because the parameters getline takes is (stream, string, delimiter).

For some reason, it only gets the first word of the sentence as well and not the rest.

Previous post

---

I want to read a txt file line by line and after reading each line, I want to split the line according to the tab "\t" and add each part to an element in a struct.

my struct is 1*char and 2*int

```
struct myStruct
{
    char chr;
    int v1;
    int v2;
}
```

where chr can contain more than one character.

A line should be something like:

randomstring TAB number TAB number NL

SOLUTION

```
std::ifstream file("plop");
std::string   line;

while(std::getline(file, line))
{
    std::stringstream   linestream(line);
    std::string         data;
    int                 val1;
    int                 val2;

    // If you have truly tab delimited data use getline() with third parameter.
    // If your data is just white space separated data
    // then the operator >> will do (it reads a space separated word into a string).
    std::getline(linestream, data, '\t');  // read up-to the first tab (discard tab).

    // Read the integers using the operator >>
    linestream >> val1 >> val2;
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

At the following code line, the data variable will hold the complete line. And linestream will be consumed, so further readings will not yield anything.

```
std::getline(linestream, data, '\t');  // read up-to the first tab (discard tab).
```

Instead, you can just work on the line like this

```
    while (std::getline(file, line))
    {
        int token1 = std::stoi(line.substr(0, line.find(" : ")));
        line.erase(0, line.find(" : ") + 3);

        int token2 = std::stoi(line.substr(0, line.find(" : ")));
        line.erase(0, line.find(" : ") + 3);

        std::string token3 = line;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is your problem ?

```
//Title of this code
//clang 3.4

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

struct Data
{
    int n1;
    int n2;
    std::string sequence;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ostr, const Data& data)
{
    ostr << "{" << data.n1 << "," << data.n2 << ",\"" << data.sequence << "\"}";
    return ostr;
}

std::string& ltrim(std::string& s, const char* t = " \t")
{
    s.erase(0, s.find_first_not_of(t));
    return s;
}

std::string& rtrim(std::string& s, const char* t = " \t")
{
    s.erase(s.find_last_not_of(t) + 1);
    return s;
}

std::string& trim(std::string& s, const char* t = " \t")
{
    return ltrim(rtrim(s, t), t);
}

int main()
{
    std::string file_content{
        "1\t1\t\n"
        "2\t2\tsecond sequence\t\n"
        "3\t3\tthird sequence\n"};

    std::istringstream file_stream{file_content};
    std::string line;
    std::vector<Data> content;
    while(std::getline(file_stream, line))
    {
        std::istringstream line_stream{line};
        Data data{};
        if(!(line_stream >> data.n1 >> data.n2))
        {
            std::cout << "Failed to parse line (numbers):\n" << line << "\n";
            break;
        }

        auto numbers_end = line_stream.tellg();
        if(numbers_end == -1)
        {
            std::cout << "Failed to parse line (sequence):\n" << line << "\n";
            break;
        }

        data.sequence = line.substr(numbers_end);
        trim(data.sequence);

        content.push_back(std::move(data));
    }

    std::copy(content.cbegin(), content.cend(),
        std::ostream_iterator<Data>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

[Live](http://rextester.com/FENC34665)

[Live with colons](http://rextester.com/UFS76687)